# Import a CSV to my Django Models

Tags: python, django, csv

I need help in order to upload a CSV to my models. I saw that there are some other questions, but they are old, or written in 2.7 and doesn't make no sense.

These are my models.

```
class Ofac_Sdn(models.Model):
    number = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
    b_i = models.CharField(max_length=250, null=True)
    programe= models.CharField(max_length=250, null=True)
    last_name= models.CharField(max_length=250, null=True)
    more_info = models.CharField(max_length=250, null=True)
    vessel_call_sign = models.CharField(max_length=250, null=True)
    vessel_type= models.CharField(max_length=250, null=True)
    vessel_dwt = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    tonnage = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    vessel_flag = models.CharField(max_length=250, null=True)
    vessel_owner= models.CharField(max_length=250, null=True)
    dob_aka= models.CharField(max_length=250, null=True)
```

This is the model of a row from my CSV:

```
36,AEROCARIBBEAN AIRLINES,-0- ,CUBA,-0- ,-0- ,-0- ,-0- ,-0- ,-0- ,-0- ,-0-
```

I have tried until now this example, but i receive an error saying: *ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'settings'*

If someone could help, I would owe you a lot as i am stuck here!

Thank you!

```
import csv, sys, os

project_dir = "/Users/cohen/my-python-project/venv/ofac/ofac_project/ofac_sdn/"

sys.path.append(project_dir)

os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE']='settings'

import django
django.setup()

from ofac_sdn.models import Ofac_Sdn

data = csv.reader(open('/Users/cohen/my-python-project/venv/ofac/ofac_project/ofac_sdn/sdn.csv')) #,delimiter="|")
#data = csv.reader(open('/Users/cohen/my-python-project/venv/ofac/ofac_project/ofac_sdn/sdn2.csv'), dialect='excel-tab')
for row in data:
    if row[0] !="Number":
        post = Ofac_Sdn()
        post.number = row[0]
        post.name = row[1]
        post.b_i=row[2]
        post.programe=row[3]

        post.more_info=row[4]
        post.vessel_call_sign=row[5]
        post.vessel_type=row[6]
        post.vessel_dwt=row[7]
        post.tonnage=row[8]
        post.vessel_flag=row[9]
        post.vessel_owner=row[10]
        post.dob_aka=row[11]
        post.save()
```

Answer (score 2):

The error has nothing to do with CSV importing.

The error is saying there is no such module with the path `settings`. This means that the you put the wrong path here:

```
os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE']='settings'
```

It should be `project_name.settings` or the path that fits your project.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

i think you need add you project name:

```
os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE']='project_name.settings'
#                                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

and you can look for [django-import-export](https://github.com/django-import-export/django-import-export) it can be simple solution

Comment: thank you! there is a video tutorial on how to use this import-export module?

Comment: i never use video tutorial, but you good [docs here](http://django-import-export.readthedocs.io/en/stable/)